# How to keep selected item displayed in dropdownlist VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu

Ok so I am fairly new to VB.Net. I needed a way to be able to navigate away from the current page to a variety of pages. I used a ddl. So if I am on page one, and want to go to page 6, I just open the ddl select page 6 and boom. 
Here is my problem. When using the ddl, after I select page 6 it automatically takes me to it, but then go back to 1 in the ddl. How do I get the ddl to display the page I am on?

Comment: Are the pages in an indexed array?

Comment: No, they are pulling from a database

Comment: In what type of control are the pages displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to determine which page is loading and use that to set the ddl. The simplest way to do it is look at the url. I'm assuming the values in the ddl are the same as the page names.

```
Sub Page_Load

  Dim filename As String = Request.Url.AbsolutePath 
  ' You probably need to do some string manipulation on filename to 
  ' make it match the values in the ddl.

  'Databind your DropDownList however you're already doing it
  ddl.Items.FindByValue(filename).Selected = true

End Sub
```